# Unable to fetch URL of window containing an alert box while initialization using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, alert

I am unable to handle getCurrentUrl() method when alert is present at the initialization of url.

Comment: Please provide more clear well organized questions with your code here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing more details I can only assume that an alert opens when you load the page but you want to get the current URL of the page? In this case you have to handle the alert before performing `getCurrentUrl()`. To do so you can simply use:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
```

The alert will be closed and you can continou your test and perform a `getCurrentUrl()`. If this is not the solution you should provide more details on your problem (what is your code, does an exception occur etc.)